# How to properly import header files in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

[image]

I import the PaiLifeCardLeftViewController.h but Xcode told me it is a unknown type.

How can I fix this, thank you.

edit: PaiLifeCardLeftViewController.h:
[image]

Comment: can you show us `PaiLifeCardLeftViewController.h`?

Comment: @Sebastian Here it is. PaiLifeCardLeftViewController.h

Comment: You just used an incorrect case just as Xcode suggested in your screenshot. Pai **L** ifeCardLeftViewController !

Comment: @Jxdwinter it would be better to paste the code in the question, rather than posting screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is being caused by a circular dependency between `PaiLifeCardLeftViewController` and `PaiLifeCardCenterViewController`. Each of the corresponding .h files are trying to import the other. You can't do this.

The proper solution is to update both .h files. In both, remove the import of the other .h and replace it with an `@class` forward declaration.

PaiLifeCardLeftViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PaiLifeCardRefreshDelegate.h"

@class PaiLifeCardCenterViewController;

@interface PaiLifeCardLeftViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, non atomic) id<PaiLifeCardRefreshDelegate> delegate

@end
```

Make a similar change to `PaiLifeCardCenterViewController.h`.

Then you must add the import to the .m file.

You should have as few imports in a .h file as possible. It's always better to use forward (`@class`) declarations when possible. It avoids circular dependencies and it makes compilation a little faster and results in fewer recompiles when .h files are changed.

Side - note. There is no need to declare the instance variable for `delegate`. It will be synthesized for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a forward class declaration to the class by adding

`@class PaiLifeCardCenterViewController`

before the `@interface` statement.